# In what way is KeeLoq a block cipher?

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, lfsr

I'm just going by [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0.png) of KeeLoq encryption and it resembles these diagrams of [Crypto-1](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/10/Crypto1.png) and [Hitag2](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/infotools/leakwatch/examples/images/hitag2.png). I'm wondering how it is a block cipher. If it is one and that diagram represents most or all of its design, then it is a very exotic block cipher.

Answer (score 1):

KeeLoq works on 32 bit blocks as opposed to arbitrarily-sized inputs. This by definition makes it a block cipher.

There's even this from the first paragraph of [Microchip's description](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/91002a.pdf):

> KEELOQ is a proprietary block cipher based on a block length of 32
>   bits and a key length of 64 bits.

**edit**: the diagram is rather unclear. The input and output both end up in the 32 bit register (NLFSR) and the key goes into the 64 bit register (FSR).

For a clearer diagram, see pages 3 and 4 of this [Keeloq cryptanalysis paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/055.pdf) which at least gives some temporal dimension to the diagram.

Comment: That doesn't shine any light on this mystery. KeeLoq operates on 32-bit blocks, fine. I wasn't disputing that it was a block cipher, I am asking what part of the diagram makes it a block cipher. I see a register for the key, I see 32-bit non-linear feedback shift register, I see a number that supposedly represents a filter, and I see the operator for bitwise XOR, but I see nothing about input or output.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited my answer with more info. The wiki page could use a better diagram.

Comment: Aha! Then it *is* an exotic block cipher. Spending more time looking at and reading about the usual design paradigms neutered the imagination I used to have when coming up with ciphers.